# start a window with a list of documents when clicking in a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I would like to create a template which I would use to order my applications to find a new job.

For each line, I will need a contact (from my contact list), a document (from my documents list) and a task list.
I want to input a hyperlink in cells to each of those documents.

I am searching for a way to display a pop-up, a frame, whatever with the list of documents or contacts from my google account.
The use would choose (click) for the good one. 
Then, the hyperlink to the chosen element would be pasted in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is part of my answer :

I have to use google scripts in spreadsheet to perform this kind of operations .

There is a script called Contact manager in the script gallery that allows you to retrieve contacts directly from google.

Here is a hint about checkboxes in google spreadsheets :
https://sites.google.com/a/simpleappssolutions.com/building-powerful-web-applications-in-google-apps-script/check-box

Now, What I have to do is concatenate all that :)